# Sencha Touch 2.3 project without microloader build error

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I changed the new project created with Sencha Cmd v4.0 so it is not using microloader anymore. For doing this I removed microloader from index.html, added scripts for ST and app, and styles. The app works well in browser and console log is free of errors or warnings. Then, making testing build stops at the error:

```
...
[INF] -build-output-microload-page:
[INF] Writing content to /home/kio21/work/st1/build/testing/St1/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to /home/kio21/work/st1/build/testing/St1/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to /home/kio21/work/st1/build/testing/St1/index.html
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERR]   at com.sencha
[ERR] .command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:394)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 5 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/kio21/work/st1/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:377: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/kio21/work/st1/.sencha/app/page-impl.xml:116: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/kio21/work/st1/.sencha/app/page-impl.xml:53: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
...
```

Trying to tune app.json or testing.properties files didn't give me success. The same approach worked well for previous Sencha Touch 2.2.1 version, but not on current 2.3.0 version. Please advise how can I build ST 2.3.0 app without microloader.

Comment: Why don't you want the microloader?

Comment: @arthurakay, I am not using the functionality Sencha's microloader proposes. I do not use delta updates and I am enough with html5 cache manifest.

Comment: @Breiz Actually I started to use microloader.. When build package or native builds using cordova, it's rather accepted for me. Looks microloader code is not too large in package build unlike in production. Also looks like files load fast enough, the loaders blue screen is usually not visible by an eye. I don't use any of `update` properties in app.json config also. The Sencha command's build process is rather convenient for me, especially when using sencha's cordova build process when you just typing `sencha app build native`, so I left the microloader by this time as basically accepted for me